Accidentally removed an old phone from my iCloud account without retrieving the photos
Accidentally removed an old phone from my iCloud account without retrieving the photos. I don't have the old phone anymore. Anyway to get back those photos?

Do you have backups of that phone?  Did you sync the photos to iCloud?

Without phone and backup, the photos are gone.
